# arr.map(Number) where map has no arguments, only Number function?

Tags: javascript

this is a line from code to multiply all digits of a number till we get a single digit number.

```
while(num.length>1){
 num = num.split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) =>  a * b).toString();
}
```

I understood how it works, but am confused with the way map is called.
From what I have learned, we need to pass map a function and pass to that function arguments which map will use as elements from that function, its index and the array itself. I have seen anonymus function in map and at least one argument passed which is for the element of array.
But in this line of code, we only pass Number function and dont explicitly pass any argument to Number.
So I tried function Number(value) and Number(value) but VScode editor didnt accepet either.
Can someone please explain how this works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343478/what-does-mapnumber-do-here

Comment: yes this is the post I read first before posting my question. Will read it again.

Comment: Got the answer reading again. Just did 

num = num.split('').map((str, ind, arr) => Number(str, ind, arr)).reduce((a, b) =>  a * b).toString();

and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(num.length>1){
 num = num.split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) =>  a * b).toString();
}
```

`num.split('')` converts every single character in a string into an array element
`.map(Number)` takes each element of the newly created array and passes it into the `Number()` function. This is a shortcut way of writing this `.map(el => Number(el))`

`reduce(a, b)` takes each item of the now numeric array (`b`) and creates a running tally, `a`

This function will repeat until there is a zero somewhere in `num` at which point it will zero out (`b * 0`) and cease.

```js
num = "12345679123123343234432327";
while (num.length > 1) {
  num = num.split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a * b).toString();
  console.log(num)
}
//console.log(num)
```